# why is page object name erroring in ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

So here is my delema... I'm trying to get page object up and running, something I've done a thousand times before, but i'm getting a name error now.  Is it just too early in the morning or am I missing something here?  It keeps throwing a NameError

```
class LoginPage
  include PageObject

  text_field(:user, :id => 'username')
  text_field(:pass, :id => 'password')
  button(:login_button, :name => 'login')


  def login (username, password)
    self.user = username
    self.pass = password
    self.login_button.click
  end

end
```

Run cucumber

```
uninitialized constant LoginPage::PageObject (NameError)
```

env.rb has

```
require 'page-object'
```

see screen shot

[image]

Comment: So the issue was that my support folder was outside my feature folder

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your require should actually be

```
require 'page_object'
```

You may even need to include a path to help it resolve it, but try replacing the hyphen with an underscore first and see whether that works.

Comment: no, it's page-object, of that i'm sure.  I have the gem included into the project, but I'm still getting a NameError on the Include

Comment: Ah; your original question didn't make it clear you were using a gem.  In that case, are you sure that rubymine is including env.rb when launching cucumber?

Comment: if rubymine was not including env.rb, then the require statement wouldn't work and the gem would not be included in the "external libraries" section of the project

Comment: When launching cucumber, I said, not inside the IDE environment itself.  Check your cucumber launch settings and perhaps include a sysout in env.rb, then check it's actually printed when you launch your cucumber scenarios from inside Rubymine.

Comment: I know it's old question, but did writing World(PageObject::PageFactory) in your environment file solved this issue?